# Return parent match in nested loop using ES6

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6

I have an array of region objects that each contain an array of countries. I want to return a region as soon as one of its country iso codes matches the pre-populated `this.isoCodes.code`. The current code uses a nested loop with breaks, but it's messy. Looking for a cleaner solution with ES6 if possible. I know there are things like `.map` with `.every` or `.some` but not sure what would give me the correct result.

The current working code looks like

```
let result;

for (let i=0; i<regions.length; i++) {
  for (let j=0; j<regions[i].countries.length; j++) {
    let country = regions[i].countries[j];
    if (country.iso2 === this.isoCodes.code || country.iso3 === this.isoCodes.code) {
      result = regions[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  if (result) {
    break;
  }
}
if (result) {
  this.region = result;
  return result;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest added some example data for your question?

Comment: you could wrap in lambda that would allow you to do a return rather than multiple breaks. Also you can use Array.includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `.find` to iterate over the `regions` and `.some` to see if any of the `country`s in a `region` pass the test:

```
const { code } = this.isoCodes;
const foundRegion = regions.find(({ countries }) => (
  countries.some(({ iso2, iso3 }) => (
    iso2 === code || iso3 === code
  ))
));
if (foundRegion) {
  this.region = foundRegion;
  return foundRegion;
}
return false;
```

Comment: I love it when code looks like a work of art! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming this is similar to the data
const isoCodes = {
  code: 'foo',
};

const regions = [
  {
    countries: [
      { iso2: 'foo', iso3: 'foo' },
      { iso3: 'bar' },
    ],
  },
];

return regions.reduce((acc, region) => {
  // already found region, skip
  if(acc) {
    return acc;
  }

  // check if any country matches in region, if so we use it
  const [first] = region.countries.filter(({ iso2, iso3 }) => 
    (iso2 === isoCodes.code || iso3 === isoCodes.code));
  if (first) {
    return region;
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzncxg2v/1/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use _.find() from js library [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find):

```
var users = [
{ 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
{ 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
{ 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

_.find(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
```